# How to make NodeJS hide path errors from the user while in production (when an error occurs)

Tags: node.js, path, directory, hide, production-environment

Recently, I have encountered the following error in one of our production environment, as an end-user making a request:

```
PayloadTooLargeError: request entity too large
        at readStream (/SOMEPATH//node_modules/raw-body/index.js:155:17)
        at getRawBody (/SOMEPATH//node_modules/raw-body/index.js:108:12)
        at read (/SOMEPATH//node_modules/body-parser/lib/read.js:77:3)
        at jsonParser (/SOMEPATH//node_modules/body-parser/lib/types/json.js:135:5)
        at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/SOMEPATH//node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
        at trim_prefix (/SOMEPATH//node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:317:13)
        at /SOMEPATH//node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:7
```

I was wondering how can I hide all of those directory paths being thrown to the client, or the error being thrown like that in the first place, as this is a production environment and that may eventually be a security issue.

Is that a possible solution (at the start of the file?):
`process.env.NODE_ENV = 'production';`
Thank you.

Comment: Could use try catch with logging, so when an exception occurs it will be logged in a file instead of thrown at frontend

Comment: Thought about it, but because it's the size of the request itself, what should I wrap the try catch around?